# Как связать данные двух отдельных программы в одну?

Tags: c++

Не знаю возможно ли это сделать или нет, поэтому и спрашиваю.

У меня есть две программы

```
main.cpp

// инициализация массива только тут!
int numbers[4] = {1,2,3,4};

int main()
{

std::cout << numbers[3] << std::endl;

return 0;
};
```

и вторая программа у которой нету инициализации массива, но я бы хотел его вызвать

```
main2.cpp
// сейчас эта программа не знает не про какой массив numbers
int main()
{

std::cout << numbers[3] << std::endl;

return 0;
};
```

Я запускаю вначале программу `main.cpp` и потом могу запустить программу `main2.cpp`
Мне интересно могу ли я получить данные с первой программы, и подключить их к другой программе.

Это нужно сделать максимально быстро, что бы программа под номером `main2.cpp` считывала и использовала данные как будто это ее часть.

Любы идеи или вопросы если не понятно.

Comment: Можно использовать [сокеты](https://lecturesnet.readthedocs.io/net/low-level/ipc/socket/intro.html) для обмена данными. Или использовать файлы, т.е. одна программа пишет данные в файл, а другая его читает.

Comment: @DSuhoi а это будет работать быстро?
сокет ведь для интернета нужен, а у меня обе программы на одном компьютере работать будут.

Comment: Почитайте [определение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81)) данного программного интерфейса ("Процессы при таком обмене могут исполняться как на одной ЭВМ, так и на различных ЭВМ, связанных между собой сетью.").

Comment: @DSuhoi хорошо я понял, надо попробовать.

Comment: [Подробнее](https://www.rsdn.org/article/unix/sockets.xml) о сокетах в C++.

Comment: Посмотрите на [shared memory](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C)

Comment: @user7860670 нет две отдельных программы надо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для передачи данных между программами на ЭВМ можно использовать UNIX-сокеты. Для использования подобного интерфейса передачи данных потребуются всего 3 библиотеки из языка Си: `sys/socket.h`, `sys/types.h` и `sys/un.h`.

Серверная часть:

```
//main2.c

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LEN_ARR 16

int main()
{
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_un addr;    //стуктура с адресом 
    int *numbers = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*LEN_ARR);  //массив для чтения данных
    int bytes_read; //количество считанных данных

    if((sock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) //создание локального сокета
    {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;  //домен

    strcpy(addr.sun_path, "mysocket");  //копирование названия файла сокета

    if(bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)  //
    {
        perror("bind");
        exit(2);
    }


    bytes_read = recvfrom(sock, numbers, LEN_ARR, 0, 0, NULL);  //т.к. принимаем 1 пакет данных, то используем recvfrom

    for(int i = 0; i< bytes_read; i++)
        printf("%d ", numbers[i]);  //выводим результат передачи
    printf("\n");

    close(sock);    //прерываем передачу

    system("rm mysocket");  //удаление файла сокета

    free(numbers);  //освобождаем память

    return 0;
}
```

Клиентская часть:

```
//main.c

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_un addr;

    int numbers[] = {1,2,3,4};  //массив для отправки

    if((sock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) //создание сокета
    {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;  //домен
    strcpy(addr.sun_path, "mysocket");  //файл сокета

    sendto(sock, numbers, sizeof(numbers), 0,
           (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)); //отправляем 1 пакет данных (массив)

    close(sock);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Так, как вы написали -

> // сейчас эта программа не знает не про какой массив numbers

нет. Вы просто обязаны объявить в программе все используемые переменные. Какой бы механизм *передачи данных* вы не использовали - место, куда эти данные будут помещаться, должно быть объявлено и создано.

Далее, из вашего

> Я запускаю вначале программу main.cpp и потом могу запустить программу main2.cpp

следует, что вы планируете запускать их *раздельно*, т.е. между завершением первой и началом второй должно пройти время. В таком случае у вас есть единственный вариант - сохранение первой программой данных на некотором носителе (в файле), с тем, чтобы вторая программа считывала их.

Более (а как по мне - самый) простой вариант был бы, если ваши программы запустить одновременно и вывод первой подать на вход второй, командной строкой с применением `|` - типа,

```
main1.exe | main2.exe
```

Тогда все, выводимое первой программой в `cout`, шло вы второй в `cin`, так что если бы ваша первая программа оставалась той же, а вторая имела вид

```
int main()
{
    int numbers[4];
    std::cin >> numbers[3];
    std::cout << numbers[3] << std::endl;
};
```

то она бы прочла число, выведенное первой программой (на экран от первой программы оно бы при этом не шло) и вывела на экран его сама.

Comment: Если работать с файлами это будет медленно, функция сохранение и чтение данных замедляет скорость программы в разы, особенно если данные постоянно будут записываться и читаться.

Comment: Тогда вы должны уточнить свой вопрос. Без точного ТЗ результат один - ХЗ...